# NHibernate QueryOver order by with arithmetic operations

Tags: c#, nhibernate, lambda, queryover

I've built an HQL to query some entities with CreateQuery, and I'm trying to translate it to a lambda expression using QueryOver.

The query looks for `Negocio`s within a range of `Latitude` and `Longitude`, and order them by the distance between the user and the `Negocio`. I want to convert it to a lambda expression because it's easier to maintain, but I'm stuck in the order by part.

These are the entities I have. I've omitted what is not relevant in this scenario.

```
public class Negocio
{
   public Endereco Endereco {get; set;} 
}

public class Endereco
{
    public GeoCoordenada GeoCoordenada {get; set;}
}
public class GeoCoordenada
{
   public double Latitude {get; set;}
   public double Longitude {get; set;}
}
```

This is the query that does the magic:

```
query = _session.CreateQuery(@"select distinct(n),
 SQRT(SQUARE(e.GeoCoordenada.Latitude - :lat) + SQUARE(e.GeoCoordenada.Longitude - :lon)) 
             from Negocio n inner join n.Endereco as e where 
             (e.GeoCoordenada.Latitude between (:minLat) and (:maxLat)) and 
             (e.GeoCoordenada.Longitude between (:minLon) and (:maxLon))
             order by SQRT(SQUARE(e.GeoCoordenada.Latitude - :lat) + 
             SQUARE(e.GeoCoordenada.Longitude - :lon))");`

        query.SetParameter("minLat", -90);  // random values just  
        query.SetParameter("maxLat", 90);   // for testing
        query.SetParameter("minLon", -180); 
        query.SetParameter("maxLon", 180);
        query.SetParameter("lat", 25);
        query.SetParameter("lon", 25);
```

This is what I got up to now:

```
 var query = _session.QueryOver<Negocio>()
                .JoinQueryOver(x => x.Endereco)
                .WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.GeoCoordenada.Latitude).IsBetween(-90).And(90)
                .AndRestrictionOn(x => x.GeoCoordenada.Longitude).IsBetween(-180).And(180)
```

**Important:** I can't order them after calling List() because a paging function will be added in the end of the query with `skip()` and `take()` , so, it makes no sense querying all the results at once

Any ideas on how to achieve that ordering?

Comment: This is definitely possible, but I don't have time to write up a complete answer :(. http://blog.andrewawhitaker.com/blog/2014/08/15/queryover-series-part-7-using-sql-functions/ might be relevant (disclaimer: it's my personal blog)

Comment: Nice! I've been working on a solution after studying this approach with projections and Sql Functions. It's fun that I was reading this article some time ago. As soon as I get this to work I'll post the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ArithmeticOperatorProjection`, a small extension that was written for NHibernate: http://savale.blogspot.ru/2011/04/nhibernate-and-missing.html

Your query would look something like this:

```
_session.QueryOver<Negocio>()
    .JoinQueryOver(x => x.Endereco)
    .JoinQueryOver(x => x.GeoCoordenada)
    .WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.Latitude).IsBetween(-90).And(90)
    .AndRestrictionOn(x => x.Longitude).IsBetween(-180).And(180)
    .OrderBy(
        new ArithmeticOperatorProjection(
            "+",
            NHibernateUtil.Decimal,
            new ArithmeticOperatorProjection(
                "*",
                NHibernateUtil.Decimal,
                new ArithmeticOperatorProjection("-", NHibernateUtil.Decimal, Projections.Property<GeoCoordenada>(x => x.Longitude), Projections.Constant(25m)),
                new ArithmeticOperatorProjection("-", NHibernateUtil.Decimal, Projections.Property<GeoCoordenada>(x => x.Longitude), Projections.Constant(25m))
            ),
            new ArithmeticOperatorProjection(
                "*",
                NHibernateUtil.Decimal,
                new ArithmeticOperatorProjection("-", NHibernateUtil.Decimal, Projections.Property<GeoCoordenada>(x => x.Latitude), Projections.Constant(25m)),
                new ArithmeticOperatorProjection("-", NHibernateUtil.Decimal, Projections.Property<GeoCoordenada>(x => x.Latitude), Projections.Constant(25m))
            )
    )
    .List();
```

This can be further improved by adding custom `SQRT` and `SQUARE` projections.